# Mesh of meshes in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am currently working on some 3D models for a project using three.js.

The model I am currently developing consists of a set of basic geometries used together to represent, say, a defence tower.

To put it clearly, I have 2 Boxes, 3 Cylinders to represent said tower.

Boxes:

```
var base = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(7, 0.2, 7), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xff000f}));
var head = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 1, 2.5), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xaaffff}));
```

Cylinders:

```
var body = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 5, 20), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
var leftCannon = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.35, 0.35, 4, 20), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
var rightCannon = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.35, 0.35, 4, 20), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
```

Please disregard the materials' colours, they are provisory.

The original idea is to add each of these meshes separately into the scene:

```
scene.add(base);
scene.add(body);
scene.add(head);
scene.add(leftCannon);
scene.add(rightCannon);
```

However I feel there is certainly a better way of doing this, at least a way that involves the ability to have more without decreasing perfomance.

I was thinking about using a container that would have all the geometries, and add one object to the scene instead of several.

With that in mind, I want to have a particular material for each separate mesh (for example the cannons are metalish and the base is dark) and I also want to keep the ability of translating/rotating/scaling my meshes separately (right now the tower's head moves with mouse dragging and WASD keys).

Comment: you cannot merge meshes of different material

Comment: @gaitat there is a way of merging geometries/meshes and having each geometry have his own material. Multi material

Comment: when we merge geometries it is only in the context of performance gain. there is no performance gain with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `THREE.Object3D` or `THREE.Group` and add the Meshes to that object. Add this object to the Scene. This will keep the option of transforming and changing the material from the individual pieces.